# Can you check if a post WYSIWYG field has an image in it?

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields, conditional-tags, wysiwyg

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and a WYSIWYG field type. Can you determine via php if that field has an image in the content OR is there a better was to evaluate this.

For example, if I upload an image into the editor and float if right of the text - I intend on treating the rendered container differently than a container without the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a built-in way in WordPress to determine if a content field *has* an image in it, but you can use standard PHP functions to check. For example, I've used a similar technique to check if a post's featured image has also been inserted into the post content, and if so, haven't shown the featured image again.

You haven't included any of your code, so this is just a sample you'll need to work in to what you already have.

The [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function will tell you if a specific string is inside another string. For example:

```
if( strpos( get_the_content(), '<img ' ) ){ /* this content has an image */ }
```

You could perhaps use this to add classes to your content container, so you can treat it differently in the CSS:

```
<?php
$image_class = strpos( get_the_content(), '<img ' ) ) ? 'has-image' : 'no-image';
?>

<div class="post-content <?php echo $image_class; ?>">
```

Comment: FWIW I've just spent a day or two looking through wp-includes/media.php and related core files and can concur that there isn't a helpful function for this.  There are functions to pull out a list of media embeds or gallery images from a piece of content, and `get_media_embedded_in_content` might be usable for the OP's purpose but if all you're after is a yes/no on an image being present then Tim's answer seems the easy way to check.

Comment: Tim, Thanks for the follow up on this! I ended up checking via jquery on load and just curious which would be technically more efficient? I know I originally asked about doing this in php. Just curious. @AndyMacaulay-Brook, thanks for that reference,I wasn't aware something like this existed!!

Comment: My rule of thumb is - generally - if it can be done in the PHP, do it there. It's almost always more efficient to do it server-side, especially because if what you're doing is cached, it's pretty much done once rather than many times. In this case also, you avoid a flash of unstyled content before jQuery applies the class. This is just a rule of thumb though... every situation is different :)